# Manual Offset in Kafka Consumer

Tags: project-reactor, reactor, reactor-kafka

I want to write a Kafka consumer and write the record in Bigquery, I want to commit the offsets manually on successful insertion in Bigquery. I have a written a sample code but it is not working, can someone help

```
ReceiverOptions<Integer, String> options = receiverOptions.subscription(Collections.singleton(topic))

        Flux<ReceiverRecord<Integer, String>> kafkaFlux1 = KafkaReceiver.create(options).receive()
                .doOnNext(r -> {
                    try {
                        writeBigquery(r);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    r.receiverOffset().commit().block();
    });

        return kafkaFlux1.subscribe(record -> {
            System.out.println("hello"+record);
        });
```

Comment: What does it mean 'not working'? Any error (if yes, what is the error)? Any behaviour you do not expect (or something that you expect does not happen)?

Comment: I tried debugging it and it was not going inside writeBigqueryMethod itself.

Comment: It's hard to tell what goes wrong. Are there messages in the topic? If yes, make sure that `auto.offset.reset` is not `latest` as otherwise you will not receive any message already existing in the topic. I'd explicitly set `auto.offset.reset` to `earliest`.